# Spinner OnItemSelected With Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-adapter

I have a `Spinner` that uses a custom adapter where the getView() is overridden. I'm having trouble capturing the `OnItemSelected` event, which I believe is related to the custom adapter. In my onCreate(), I have this:

```
superGroupAdapter = new SuperGroupAdapter(context, R.layout.row_sg, sg_list);
sgSpinner.setAdapter(superGroupAdapter);

sgSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "sg spinner on item selected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});
```

And this is my custom adapter class:

```
public class SuperGroupAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    @Inject SharedVisualElements sharedVisualElements;

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> sg_list;

    public SuperGroupAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> sg_list) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, sg_list);

        // add this line for any class that want to use any of the singleton objects
        Injector.INSTANCE.getAppComponent().inject(this);

        this.context = context;
        this.sg_list = sg_list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        parent.setBackgroundColor(sharedVisualElements.backgroundColor());

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_sg, parent, false);

        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sg_name);
        label.setText(sg_list.get(position));
        label.setTypeface(sharedVisualElements.font());
        label.setTextColor(sharedVisualElements.primaryFontColor());
        label.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        return row;
    }
}
```

When the activity initializes, I see the log output

> sg spinner on item selected

But that is the last time I see it. No matter how many times I select an item from the spinner, it never fires again. I've looked all over for a way to trap this, but to no avail. Can anyone help? Thank you.

**EDIT**
I've also tried changing the class signature to implement `OnItemSelected` and declaring the listener as a separate method as is explained in the Android [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#SelectListener), but got the same result.

I'm seriously at a loss on this one. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I figured this out. After reviewing some other posts, it occurred to me that in my test data, I only had one item in my spinner list. The `OnItemSelectedListener` only fires when you *change* the selection.

From the Android docs for `OnItemSelectedListener`

> This callback is invoked only when the newly selected position is
>   different from the previously selected position or if there was no
>   selected item.

So, when the activity initialized, it selected the item at position 0. When I tapped the spinner and 'selected' the same item, this action does not fire that event. Live and learn.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing this before the adapter     `SuperGroupAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`

Answer (score 1):

Try to call **superGroupAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** after you add item to **sg_list** or change the **sg_list**.

Comment: Thanks. I never actually change the sg_list once it is created, so I don't think this is the issue. I tried it just in case, but it didn't change anything.